# Assigning multiple input parameters to an Angular Validator

Tags: angular, validation

I have a single-use custom validator in my Angular 8 project to determine if an input is required based on the value of another input.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appRequiredExplanation]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: RequiredHardshipDirective,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class RequiredExplanationDirective implements Validator {
    @Input('appRequiredExplanation') otherValue = '';

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
        return this.otherValue === MyComponent.needsExplanationReason &&
        control.value === ''
            ? { required: { value: control.value } }
            : null;
    }
}
```

The current `@Input` of `otherValue` is the form value of the first radio group. `MyComponent.needsExplanationReason` is a static property that contains the value for the first radio group that requires additional information.

I now have another component that has the same paradigm and I would like to make this reusable by creating another `@Input` for that static property.

Right now, I'm accessing it like this in my HTML:

```
<textarea
    name="mainReasonExtraInfo"
    placeholder="Please provide additional information"
    [(ngModel)]="model.mainReasonExtraInfo"
    appRequiredExplanation="model.mainReason"
></textarea>
```

If I add another `@Input` to the Validator, how would I provide that information in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#bind-to-a-second-property) does cover how to do this. I had tried Googling, but it never came up on the first two pages.

You can simply add another `@Input` to the Directive and just continue to add more attributes to your DOM element.

```
export class RequiredExplanationDirective implements Validator {
    // Providing the name here allows us to assign a value to the declaration call.
    @Input('appRequiredExplanation') otherValue = '';
    @Input() compareValue = '';

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
        return this.otherValue === this.compareValue &&
        control.value === ''
            ? { required: { value: control.value } }
            : null;
    }
}
```

Then in your DOM just set it up as another property.

```
<textarea
    name="mainReasonExtraInfo"
    placeholder="Please provide additional information"
    [(ngModel)]="model.mainReasonExtraInfo"
    appRequiredExplanation="model.mainReason"
    compareValue="needsExplanationReason"
></textarea>
```